# when the generator stop for python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, generator, yield

I have python3 function like:

```
def previous_current(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    prv = None
    cur = it.__next__()
    try:
        while True:
            yield prv,cur
            prv = cur
            cur = it.__next__()
    except StopIteration:
        yield prv, None
```

I find it the yield naturally stop, not execute except phase.
like I invoke:

```
s1 = [1,2,3]
g = previous_current(s1)
for i in range(len(s1)):
    pre, cur = next(g)
    print(pre, cur)
```

it print:

```
None, 1
1, 2
2, 3
```

I just do not know I have while True condition, I think it will continue to run until error.
But for this, it seems to stop when the list ends. I do not know why it runs like this. I think it should give result like:

```
None, 1
1, 2
2, 3  
3, None
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(s1))`, is too short, add a +1, `for i in range(len(s1) + 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user504909 - this is because your range(len(s1)):
So if you want to include 3, then as earlier post suggests you should change it to have it - range(len(s1)+1) then.

```py
The range() function has two sets of parameters, as follows:

range(stop)

stop: Number of integers (whole numbers) to generate, starting from zero. eg. range(3) == [0, 1, 2].
```